# What happens if there is stoppage of play after a tied T20 International match and super over is not possible?

Tags: cricket

Let's say, the two innings are completed with scores level. Normally, a super over would decide the winner but if there is, say, a rain interruption and the super over cannot be completed, how is the match awarded?

Comment: What playing conditions are in effect?

Comment: A downvote? I updated the question to indicate an international match.

Comment: In [IPL](http://www.iplt20.com/about/2016/match-playing-conditions/26/law-21-the-result), for group stages,

1 point per team taking part in any match with no result or any match which is tied (where it was not possible to complete a Super Over at the end of play or where the Super Over itself is tied).

Not sure about T20 international.

Answer (score 1):

The number of runs scored by boundaries comes into the effect.. The team which scored most runs from boundaries will win the match.
Even if both of them are same then runs from sixes are given preference.
If still they are equal... then i guess may be number of wickets are considered or both teams are declared winners

Comment: Welcome to SE.Sport. Could you please add any (official) references to your answer?

Comment: @Ale The answer i have given is purely on my knowledge of cricket. I can't exactly give you the perfect rule because... it depends on the tournament you are playing... rules change from IPL to ICC. Also leagues like BBL , CPL, BPL, PSL also follow their own rules. I can only give you the rules if you mention the tournament.

Comment: So that means your answer needs to be updated with the rules you're discussing. That's why we ask for references, to ensure answers are of the highest quality possible.